# RepeatDirection Property for CheckedListBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, web-controls

so I'm very confused here. I want to make my multilined `CheckedListBox` to be sorted horizontally. I've done some research and it is all leading to the `RepeatDirection` property. [Example in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatdirection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But I don't have a web page and I don't know any XML. Can't I just somehow use this property for the `CheckedListBox` Control? The MSDN people say it is already a property of that Control as they simply have written:

```
public virtual RepeatDirection RepeatDirection { get; set; }
```

I just can't seem to understand how to implement this in my code!
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I don't have a web form! It is a `System.Windows.Forms`project. I just tagged web-controls because the `RepeatDirection` property seems to exist in the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace.

Comment: Of course you can. In your `.aspx` markup page, where you have defined your `<asp:CheckBoxList... />` simply set `RepeatDirection` property. For example it would go like this `<asp:CheckBoxList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ... />`. You can see full example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.repeatdirection(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Michael What is a ".aspx markup page" ? My code is in C# and I can't find any .aspx if I search the solution explorer!

Comment: Yeah, if you're using win forms then you can't use `RepeatDirection` on your control, as you mentioned in your post that is part of `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace. What you can try thou is to set `MultiColumn=true` on your `CheckedBoxList` control and try to adjust width of your control to have it shown its items horizontally.

Comment: @Michael I already did that. My CheckedListBox is already 4 rows long. 
[(1)  (4)  (7)]  
[(2)  (5)  (8)]
[(3)  (6)  (9)]
The only stupid thing is that I can't sort its elements like this:

[(1)  (2)  (3)]  
[(4)  (5)  (6)]
[(7)  (8)  (9)]

Comment: The text editor on this website is so.. smart.
Anyway what I'm trying to achieve is to get the numbers to start at the first row like 1,2,3 and the second 4,5,6 and so on and so forth.

Comment: __If__ you can make sure that __no scrollbars__  are needed you can add the items in the order you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. ListBox as implemented in the Windows Forms does not support repeating horizontally. You aren't using the web version of the control, so you can't use the web version's options.

If you still need to display your options horizontally you will need to use a different control. Depending on your requirements, a DataGridView should be able to do what you are wanting, with some tweaking.