# CheckedListBox RepeatDirection property in Windows Forms, C#

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm very confused here. I want to make my multilined `CheckedListBox` to be sorted horizontally. I've done some research and it is all leading to the `RepeatDirection` property. Example in the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatdirection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But I don't have a web page and I don't know any XML. Can't I just somehow use this property for the `CheckedListBox` Control? The MSDN people say it is already a property of that Control as they simply have written:

`public virtual RepeatDirection RepeatDirection { get; set; }`

I just can't seem to understand how to implement this in my code!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using a WinForms control, but reading WPF help.  There is no such property for your control.

Comment: BTW, you already asked this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579521/repeatdirection-property-for-checkedlistbox-c-sharp